# How to I put an image to the side of my combo box?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want put an image with the name in a drop down box.

JavaScript:

```
var teams = [
        ["Barcelona", "images/logo/Barcelona.jpg"],
        ["Real Madrid", "images/logo/RMadrid.jpg"]]

for(i=0;i<teams.length;i++){
                var select = document.getElementById("test");
                select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(teams[i][0], "<img src=" + teams[i][1]+">" );
            }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
</select>
```

Comment: IMHO `myArr.push(...)` beats `myArr[myArr.length] = ...` any day

Comment: you can't - you should look at `select2`.

Comment: You will need to use some kind of custom implementation, because `select` element only accept `option` and this doesn't accept custom content, only text labels. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option There is lots of tutorials online you can use, probably you will find something with the elements `ul` and `li` to get the result you want, like this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/